# How to fix server clock time?

Tags: php, javascript

[There](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/servertime.shtml) is a simple javascript code to create clock based on server time. At the begining they check server time via php and then just raise his value with js +1000. But if you are on site longer clock begin lose accuracy. Like, when I am on site 30 minutes there is a 5 min delay and it is little bit much. Is there some way how to fix this problem?

Comment: ping the server and get the time every few minutes and readjust.

Comment: In relation to the above, also take into account the transmission time of the request and response.

Comment: Just calculate the difference between client-time & server-time on load, and show a time with that offset... If your client happens to change time(zones) in between, well, I can live with a faulty clock at that point for a little while.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sync javascript countdown timer with server](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10322796/1409082)

Comment: They're using `setInterval` to advance the time, instead of displaying an accurate `Date` object. Throw that script away!

Answer (score 1):

> At the begining they check server time via php and then just raise his value with js +1000. But if you are on site longer clock begin lose accuracy. Like, when I am on site 30 minutes there is a 5 min delay and it is little bit much.

That’s because the script creates a JavaScript Date object only once, and then “hopes” for execution of the code that adds one second to that object every 1000 ms – which will not occur, because the browser is busy doing other stuff in-between, like handling user (mouse) input, scrolling, whatever.

> Is there some way how to fix this problem?

The script should create a *new* Date object on every loop, and calculate the difference between that and the originally given start value. (Or could be a combination of both, if performance is a severe concern – create new Date object every x loops, and add x seconds in between to this “updated” current timestamp.)